# How to set task fields while assigning a new task?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I'm creating a WF with SharePoint designer 2013.

The work flow should be approved by 3 company members. So, I added a new column to my custom WF task list called "Approval stage" which is a choice column and should has values "Analyst, Reviewer and Manager".

When assigning a task for each user, I need to set the value of this column.

For now, I can update it only after the task is finished (approved or rejected). But I need to set it in the assigning process.

How can I do it??

Answer (score 0):

When you create a task you will get an output as an ID on the basis of that you can update the field related to that task item.

Comment: Output is 0 or 1. TaskID is the one you mean.

Comment: Update a task is only done after the task is assigned. I need to set some value at the assigning process. For example you set task title and description. I need to set other fields, as well.